# Georeferencing Polygon Features using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, editing, georeferencing, ground-control

I am using ArcGIS Pro to perform an image classification. To do this I need training data polygons derived from the image which is being classified. I created training data polygons outlining features of an underlying raster. I forgot to georeference the underlying raster before creating the training data. Now, after I performed the georeferencing of the underlying raster, my training data does not align with my raster. No matter what I do to manually move, rotate or scale my training data, it will not align with my underlying raster.

Is there any way to use control point to actually georeference the training data polygons onto the underlying raster?

It took a long time to create all the training data, so I am trying to avoid recreating the entire set.

Answer (score 1):

The vector equivalent to georeferencing of raster data is spatial adjustment.  To do that in ArcGIS Pro see [Is the Spatial Adjustment toolbar available in ArcGIS Pro?](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-is-the-spatial-adjustment-toolbar-available-in-arcg-000026553).

That FAQ refers you to the Online Help for how to [Transform features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/transform-a-feature.htm):

> The **Transform** tool changes the geometric shape of selected
> features using displacement links to specify known locations and
> corresponding destination locations.